# Assign Maximum no. of attempts for while loop

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

My Last experience with Stackoverflow was awesome and I thank everyone who helped me.
I am now trying to scrape different pages on this website in the code.

However, when I am trying to click the next page, I have the following concerns and I am not sure how to pass them,

1) The Xpath for the next page button changes with the total no. of search results.
For eg. if there are 5 pages, then the xpath is //html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[7]/a'
And if there are 10 then the xpath is 
//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[12]/a'

I decided to create 2 different scripts for those with 10 pages or more and one for less than 10 pages,
However even when I do that, I still can't make the script stop because the script keeps clicking the next page even when the next page button is disabled in the browser. IT IS IMPOSSIBLE FOR ME TO MAKE THE SCRIPT STOP AFTER CERTAIN NO. OF ATTEMPTS.

Could some one please advise a work around for this.
I am only pasting the code for surfing through the pages, since extracting the data would be easy once python knows where to stop!

Thanks in advance, here is my code.

```
import fileinput
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import lxml.html
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
from collections import defaultdict
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


path_to_chromedriver = 'chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
browser.get('http://targetstudy.com/school/schools-in-chhattisgarh.html')
time.sleep(3)

while ((browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[11]/a').is_enabled()):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[11]/a').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'something'
else:
    browser.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
while browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination']/li)[last()]").get_attribute("class") != "disabled":
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a)[last()]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'something'
else:
    browser.close()
```

The idea is to:

- Find the last `li`
- Test to see if the `class="disabled"` of that `li`
- If it isn't, then click the last `li/a`, which is the Next Page link

Answer (score 1):

Dear user you can use break statement in between while loop like below code
try this code and add your maximum number i hope help this.

```
counter = 0 while
((browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[11]/a').is_enabled()):
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[11]/a').click()
     time.sleep(2)
     print 'something'
     counter = counter + 1
     if counter > "Your Maximum Number":
        break

else:
     browser.close()
```